# SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, ssms

How to use SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server 2000

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Did you try anything?

Comment: Just use it - what else is there to say??

Answer (score 1):

Download it, install & run it. Works fine with every SQL Server edition.

Comment: Yeah- just use it - what else is there to say??

Answer (score 1):

SSMS 2008 will work with SQL Server 2000. You won't have access to intellisense or SQL 2008 Commands ( hierarchy, geometry, CTEs, etc) but you can run T-SQL, browse the server without issue. Just make sure you're using the correct login method.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you need intellisense working in SSMS with SQL Server 2000, you'll need some third-party tools, like our [dbForge SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/). The tool has both free and shareware editions.